# How to update SQLite database in fragment? Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I display my database in listview in a fragment. Also I add a new data in a dialog.
I have a little problem about updating database when I add some data in dialog and when I return to my fragment which displays my database in listview, there is no data which I add recently. When I close and reopen my app, data displays in listview.

I guess you understand my issue.

Here are my codes.

**Here is my MainActivity which has a button and a fragment.**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ImageButton addBirthdate;

private DB database = new DB(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    addBirthdate = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonAddBirthday);
    addBirthdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddBirthdayDialog dialog = new AddBirthdayDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}


}
```

**This my fragment where I display my database in listview.**

```
public class JanuaryFragment extends Fragment {

private DB myDB;
private List<Person> people;
private ListView listView;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.january_fragment, container, false);

    mContext = getActivity();

    myDB = new DB(mContext);
    people = getThisMonthsPeople( myDB.getAllPeople());

    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewOfBirthdays);
    listView.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(mContext, people));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            EditBirthdayDialog dialog = new EditBirthdayDialog(mContext, people.get(position));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public List<Person> getThisMonthsPeople(List<Person> allPeople){
    List<Person> resultPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();
    for(int i = 0; i< allPeople.size(); i++){
        if(allPeople.get(i).getMonth()==1){
            resultPeople.add(allPeople.get(i));
        }
    }
    return resultPeople;
}
}
```

**Here is my dialog which add a new data.**

```
public class AddBirthdayDialog extends Dialog {

private Context context;
String name;
String sname;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

final EditText textName;
final EditText textSname;
final DatePicker birthDate;

private DB myDB;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private Person person = new Person();

public AddBirthdayDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.addbirthday_layout);


    myDB = new DB(context);


    textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextname);
    textSname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextsname);
    birthDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);



    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearForm();
            dismiss();

        }
    });

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            name = textName.getText().toString();
            sname = textSname.getText().toString();

            day = birthDate.getDayOfMonth();
            month = birthDate.getMonth()+1;
            year = birthDate.getYear();
            final String dayStr = String.valueOf(day);
            final String monthStr = String.valueOf(month+1);
            final String yearStr = String.valueOf(year);

            person.setName(name);
            person.setSname(sname);
            person.setDay(day);
            person.setMonth(month);
            person.setYear(year);
            person.setDateStr(dayStr + "/" + monthStr + "/" + yearStr);

            myDB.addBirthday(person);
            clearForm();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}

public void setDatePicker(int day, int month, int year){
    birthDate.updateDate(day,month,year);
}

//Cleans the form
public void clearForm(){
    textName.setText("");
    textSname.setText("");
    textSname.setText("");
}
}
```

**Here is my dialog where I can edit my data in listview.**

```
public class EditBirthdayDialog extends Dialog {

private Context context;
String name;
String sname;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

final EditText textName;
final EditText textSname;
final DatePicker birthDate;

private DB myDB;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private Person person;

public EditBirthdayDialog(Context context, final Person person) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.person = person;

    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.editbirthday_layout);


    myDB = new DB(context);


    textName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextname);
    textName.setText(person.getName());
    textSname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextsname);
    textSname.setText(person.getSname());
    birthDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    birthDate.updateDate(person.getYear(),person.getMonth()-1,person.getDay());

    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearForm();
            dismiss();

        }
    });

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = textName.getText().toString();
            sname = textSname.getText().toString();

            day = birthDate.getDayOfMonth();
            month = birthDate.getMonth()+1;
            year = birthDate.getYear();
            final String dayStr = String.valueOf(day);
            final String monthStr = String.valueOf(month);
            final String yearStr = String.valueOf(year);

            person.setName(name);
            person.setSname(sname);
            person.setDay(day);
            person.setMonth(month);
            person.setYear(year);
            person.setDateStr(dayStr + "/" + monthStr + "/" + yearStr);

            myDB.updateBirthday(person);
            clearForm();
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondelete);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myDB.deleteBirthday(person);
            clearForm();
            dismiss();
        }
    });
}

public void setDatePicker(int day, int month, int year){
    birthDate.updateDate(day,month,year);
}

//Cleans the form
public void clearForm(){
    textName.setText("");
    textSname.setText("");
}
}
```

Edited.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Reload your data when dialog is closed. You are adding data in your database only, not refreshing your listview.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 But how can I reload :) Can you show me the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your data when dialog is closed. You are adding data in your database only, not refreshing your listview.

Add this method in your fragment

```
public void reload()
{
    myDB = new DB(mContext);
    people = getThisMonthsPeople( myDB.getAllPeople());
    myAdapter = new PersonAdapter(mContext, people)
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    if(myAdapter != null)
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Remove these three lines from `onCreateView()`

```
myDB = new DB(mContext);
people = getThisMonthsPeople( myDB.getAllPeople());
listView.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(mContext, people));
```

In your activity

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    JanuaryFragment fragment = (JanuaryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.layout); // Replace "layout" with your layout where you are loading the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.reload();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Add this in your `AddBirthdayDialog` on save button click before calling `dismiss()`

```
if(context instanceOf MainActivity)
    ((MainActivity)context).onResume();
```

**NOTE:**

I would suggest you to use Interface for these kind of behaviors. See my answer in this if you want a better solution using Interfaces. [Communicating my Dialog with Main Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680194/communicating-my-dialog-with-main-activity/27680302#27680302)

Comment: Please try now. Made a small change in `onResume` method.

Comment: This also didn't work. If you need the whole code I can post for you

Comment: You are using `EditBirthdayDialog` but have posted code for `AddBirthdayDialog`. Can you correct it?

Comment: EditBirthdayDialog is another dialog which can edit the data when I click in listView.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are calling Add dialog?

Comment: I have a mainactivity which have a button and a fragment. When I click the button, mainActivity opens AddBirthdayDialog and I can add a new data from there. And I display my datas in listview which is in JanuaryFragment

Comment: Please try now. Working on partial code is irritating...  :D

Comment: // Replace "layout" with your layout where you are loading the fragment

You meant the R.id.pager which contains the fragment in activity or you meant the R.layout.january_layout which is the layout of JanuaryFragment ? Actually I tried both of them but none of them worked.

Comment: I meant the layout where JanuaryFragment is loaded. But its unbelievable that its not working. There is something which I can't see in partial code. It simply means that onResume is not being called.

Comment: I am an amateur in android, maybe I designed my code wrong :)

Comment: Its not like that... try my last edit (keep previous changes intact)

Comment: But I would suggest you to use Interface for these kind of behaviors. See my answer in this if you want a better solution using Interfaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680194/communicating-my-dialog-with-main-activity/27680302#27680302

Comment: Learn to use Interface and it would help you a lot in future.